# Is this possible to get Hash from Jekyll page URL

Tags: jekyll, liquid

`http://127.0.0.1:4000/categories#update`

I want this `/categories/#update`

but `{{page.url}}` only showing `/categories`

Comment: `{{page.url}}` is generated by Jekyll at build-time based on the base URL, the location of the page inside the folder structure, and the permalink settings. There are no hashes there. What are you trying to achieve? Where and why do you need that `#update`?

Comment: I want this on the categories page to achieve this `{% for post in site.categories.update %}`. want to get categories according to hash in URL

Comment: You can't do that with Jekyll. Either you should generate the whole list and filter them on the frontend (JS), or generate separate pages for each category (you can do that by writing a Jekyll plugin).